# How do I make my code look for a name in my list instead of a number?

Tags: python, file, python-3.7

I have a file called classgrades.txt and it contains student data from a sample class. Each line in the file consists of a student's last name, a space, and a sequence of integers (separated by spaces), which represent scores on assignments.

I am trying to write a Python program to read the data from this file and to write a new file called classscores.txt . Each line of classscores.txt should consist of a student's last name and their average score on the assignments, rounded **down** to the nearest integer.

I've tried to find a way using the length of the list to go through it and once it reaches a name, it stops and takes all the previous numbers and finds the average and puts it next to the name.

```py
inFile = open('classgrades.txt','r')

lines = inFile.read()
outFile = open('classcores.txt','w')

fix_list = lines.replace('\n',' ')
new_list = fix_list.split(' ')
length_list = len(new_list) - 1
```

Here is what my current list looks like after this code:

`['Chapman', '90', '100', '85', '66', '80', '55', 'Cleese', '80', '90', '85', '88', 'Gilliam', '78', '82', '80', '80', '75', '77', 'Idle', '91', 'Jones', '68', '90', '22', '100', '0', '80', '85', 'Palin', '80', '90', '80', '90', '']`

It should output everything nicely in classscores.txt

Comment: Props for the Monty Python name references in your sample output! Could you share a copy of the input file (or at least a sample of a few lines of it?). You've described it very well, but it's easier to write code if we've got an example to work with. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
for i in range(0, len(new_list) - 1):
    if new_list[i][0].isalpha(): # Checks if first character in current item is a letter (found a name)
        num_of_scores = 0
        avg = 0
        for item in new_list[i + 1:len(new_list) - 1]: # Iterates through next item onward (getting the scores)
            if item[0].isnumeric():
                avg += int(item) 
                num_of_scores += 1
            else:
                break
        avg = int(avg / num_of_scores) # int() produces same effect as rounding down - cuts off decimals
        outFile.write(new_list[i] + ' ' + str(avg) + '\n')
outFile.close()
```

The logic gets a bit funky since it seems there's a variable amount of answers to each student, but it worked with that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Since our file already has each student on a different line, we can take advantage of that to easily separate them out by each `\n`. Or even better, use the built-in `str.splitlines()` method.

```py
from math import floor
from statistics import mean

inFile = open('classgrades.txt','r')
outFile = open('classcores.txt','w')

lines = inFile.read().splitlines()
students = [line.split(" ") for line in lines]

scores = []
for student in students:
    name, *grades = student
    grades_as_ints = [int(grade) for grade in grades]
    score = floor(mean(grades_as_ints))
    scores.append(name + " " + str(score) + "\n")

outFile.writelines(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that each *line* of your input file contains the name and the scores, I would use the standard approach, which would be to slam your text file into a list of lists (instead of a plain list). That will make everything easier.

The solution would be along those lines:

```
with open('classgrades.txt','r') as f:
    # let Python split by line
    lines = f.readlines()

results = [] # we will put the results as a list of (name, average_grade) 
for line in lines:
    items = line.strip().split(' ')
    name = items[0]
    # grades are the rest:
    grades = items[1:]
    grades = [int(item) for item in grades] # convert to int
    avg_grade = sum(grades) / len(grades)
    # add the result of that student to the list:
    results.append((name, avg_grade)) 

with open('classcores.txt', 'w') as f:
    for result in results:
        f.write("%s %s\n" % result)
```

Comment: I think this will get stuck because your `grades` are still `str`s. Also, note that (confusingly!) `readlines()` *doesn't* remove the trailing `\n` from the end of each line. I have to check its behaviour every time I use it... 

Comment: Thanks (I had not tested because I did not have the source file). Both issues are quite easy to fix: for the line, just use `strip()` to remove the trailing `\n`.  One should also convert the list of grades to integers. The source has been fixed accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I had the advantage of having reconstructed the file from OP's description and the sample output when I was writing my answer!  So I just ran your code with that to see if it worked. This assumes, of course, that I've correctly inferred how the file was...